# Equivalent of perwebrequest in Castle Windsor WCF integration

Tags: wcf, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

We are using Castle Windsor for the WCF Service(which handles JSON request/response). Also we are using Entity Framework in the Data Layer.

When we use `PerWebRequest` LifeStyle, it throws the following error:

```
The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'HttpContext.Current is null. PerWebRequestLifestyle can only be used in ASP.Net'. See server logs for more details. The exception stack trace is:

at Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.PerWebRequestLifestyleModule.GetScope() at Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.WebRequestScopeAccessor.GetScope(CreationContext context) at Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.ScopedLifestyleManager.GetScope(CreationContext context) at Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.ScopedLifestyleManager.Resolve(CreationContext context, IReleasePolicy releasePolicy) at Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.DefaultHandler.ResolveCore(CreationContext context, Boolean requiresDecommission, Boolean instanceRequired, Burden& burden) at Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.DefaultHandler.Resolve(CreationContext context, Boolean instanceRequired) at Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.AbstractHandler.Resolve(CreationContext context) at Castle.MicroKernel.Resolvers.DefaultDependencyResolver.ResolveFromKernelByType(CreationContext context, ComponentModel model, DependencyModel dependency) at Castle.MicroKernel.Resolvers.DefaultDependencyResolver.ResolveFromKernel(CreationContext context, ComponentModel model, DependencyModel dependency) at Castle.MicroKernel.Resolvers.DefaultDependencyResolver.ResolveCore(CreationContext context, ISubDependencyResolver contextHandlerResolver, ComponentModel model, DependencyModel dependency) at Castle.MicroKernel.Resolvers.DefaultDependencyResolver.Resolve(CreationContext context, ISubDependencyResolver contextHandlerResolver, ComponentModel model, DependencyModel dependency) at Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.CreateConstructorArguments(ConstructorCandidate constructor, CreationContext context) at Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.Instantiate(CreationContext context) at Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.InternalCreate(CreationContext context) at Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.AbstractComponentActivator.Create(CreationContext context, Burden burden) at Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.AbstractLifestyleManager.CreateInstance(CreationContext context, Boolean trackedExternally) at Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.SingletonLifestyleManager.Resolve(CreationContext context, IReleasePolicy releasePolicy) at Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.DefaultHandler.ResolveCore(CreationContext context, Boolean requiresDecommission, Boolean instanceRequired, Burden& burden) at Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.DefaultHandler.Resolve(CreationContext context, Boolean instanceRequired) at Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.AbstractHandler.Resolve(CreationContext context) at Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.ResolveComponent(IHandler handler, Type service, IDictionary additionalArguments, IReleasePolicy policy) at Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.Castle.MicroKernel.IKernelInternal.Resolve(String key, Type service, IDictionary arguments, IReleasePolicy policy) at Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.Resolve[T](String key, IDictionary arguments) at Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration.WindsorInstanceProvider.GetInstance(InstanceContext instanceContext, Message message) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.InstanceBehavior.GetInstance(InstanceContext instanceContext, Message request) at System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext.GetServiceInstance(Message message) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.InstanceBehavior.EnsureServiceInstance(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage41(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
```

When we use `PerWcfOperation` LifeStyle, it works fine, but it returns the same data from the Data Layer(In my case, it returns the same UserStatus, unless I initialize the _context before each method in the Data Layer). Below is the implementation of the GET method in the data Layer:

The below method gives the expected result from the web application when using `PerWebRequest` LifeStyle.

```
public class UserDAL: IUserDAL
{
    #region Declaration
    private MyDBContainer _context;
    #endregion

    #region Constructor
    public UserDAL()
    {
        _context = new MyDBContainer();
    }
    #endregion

    #region Get User Status
    /// <summary>
    /// Get User Status
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="user"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public User GetUserStatus(User user)
    {
        st_User _dbUser = null;
        if (user != null && user.UserId > 0)
        {
            _dbUser = _context.st_User.Where(u => u.User_Id == user.UserId && !u.Is_Deleted).SingleOrDefault();
        }
        if (_dbUser != null && _dbUser.User_Id > 0)
        {
            user.LastLoginDate = _dbUser.Last_Login_Date;
            user.UserStatus = (UserStatus)Enum.Parse(typeof(UserStatus), _dbUser.User_Status, true);
        }

        return user;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

When we use `PerWcfSession` LifeStyle, it throws the following error:

```
The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'Could not obtain scope for component MyApp.DAL.UserDAL. This is most likely either a bug in custom IScopeAccessor or you're trying to access scoped component outside of the scope (like a per-web-request component outside of web request etc)'. See server logs for more details. The exception stack trace is:

at Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.ScopedLifestyleManager.GetScope(CreationContext context) at Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.ScopedLifestyleManager.Resolve(CreationContext context, IReleasePolicy releasePolicy) at Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.DefaultHandler.ResolveCore(CreationContext context, Boolean requiresDecommission, Boolean instanceRequired, Burden& burden) at Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.DefaultHandler.Resolve(CreationContext context, Boolean instanceRequired) at Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.AbstractHandler.Resolve(CreationContext context) at Castle.MicroKernel.Resolvers.DefaultDependencyResolver.ResolveFromKernelByType(CreationContext context, ComponentModel model, DependencyModel dependency) at Castle.MicroKernel.Resolvers.DefaultDependencyResolver.ResolveFromKernel(CreationContext context, ComponentModel model, DependencyModel dependency) at Castle.MicroKernel.Resolvers.DefaultDependencyResolver.ResolveCore(CreationContext context, ISubDependencyResolver contextHandlerResolver, ComponentModel model, DependencyModel dependency) at Castle.MicroKernel.Resolvers.DefaultDependencyResolver.Resolve(CreationContext context, ISubDependencyResolver contextHandlerResolver, ComponentModel model, DependencyModel dependency) at Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.CreateConstructorArguments(ConstructorCandidate constructor, CreationContext context) at Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.Instantiate(CreationContext context) at Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.InternalCreate(CreationContext context) at Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.AbstractComponentActivator.Create(CreationContext context, Burden burden) at Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.AbstractLifestyleManager.CreateInstance(CreationContext context, Boolean trackedExternally) at Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.SingletonLifestyleManager.Resolve(CreationContext context, IReleasePolicy releasePolicy) at Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.DefaultHandler.ResolveCore(CreationContext context, Boolean requiresDecommission, Boolean instanceRequired, Burden& burden) at Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.DefaultHandler.Resolve(CreationContext context, Boolean instanceRequired) at Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.AbstractHandler.Resolve(CreationContext context) at Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.ResolveComponent(IHandler handler, Type service, IDictionary additionalArguments, IReleasePolicy policy) at Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.Castle.MicroKernel.IKernelInternal.Resolve(String key, Type service, IDictionary arguments, IReleasePolicy policy) at Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.Resolve[T](String key, IDictionary arguments) at Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration.WindsorInstanceProvider.GetInstance(InstanceContext instanceContext, Message message) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.InstanceBehavior.GetInstance(InstanceContext instanceContext, Message request) at System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext.GetServiceInstance(Message message) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.InstanceBehavior.EnsureServiceInstance(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage41(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
```

Below is how we use the Castle Windsor LifeStyle:

```
container.Register(Component.For<IUserDAL>().ImplementedBy<UserDAL>().LifeStyle.PerWcfSession());
```

Which is the best way to implement Castle Windsor for WCF an equivalent to `PerWebRequest` LifeStyle? Please suggest

Comment: can you give the whole stacktrace?

Comment: maxlego, I have updated my question with complete stacktrace.

Comment: Hello Prasad, How is the UserDal created. Is it a dependency of another component ? Or is it created using resolve. In case it is a dependency, has the parent component also a lifestyle per WcfOperation. I would expect that since you are using Wcf you would need to use PerWcfOperation.

Comment: Hi Marwijn, all the Components in my WCF has the same LifeStyle. I have tried using the PerWcfOperation, but I have an issue as I explained in my question.

Answer (score 0):

The PerWcfOperation lifestyle is exactly what you've found it to be.  The object lives throughout the operation.  It's especially valuable in a unit of work situation in which your business service that's injected with your UserDAL needs to make some db changes, do some more business logic and then make some more business changes before finally calling commit on the DbContext.

I assume you're MyDbContainer has a private DbContext instance that you're using which is why you're experiencing the shared DbContext throughout the call.

I can see two ways to go about fixing the unwanted behavior.  First, you could make your lifestyle transient as I don't see any reason in the above code why you want this to last for a wcf operation length.

Another solution, and usually how I would approach would be to make your data access a singleton and inject them with an IContextFactory (my own interface) that will spin up an appropriate lifestyled context for the occasion.